# Strange behaviour Bindings with plain Properties with Property Changed and Busy UIThread

Tags: wpf, binding, dispatcher

I have a property like this.

```
public double RollDegrees
    {
        get
        {
            return rollDegrees;
        }
        set
        {
            if (rollDegrees != value)
            {
                rollDegrees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(PROPERTY_NAME_ROLL_DEGREES);
            }
        }
```

It is binding to a xaml control and the UI updates perfect in normal conditions.
This property is updated on NON-UI Thread but as far I know it not neccesary to put the update on a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with plain properties.

But when the app is running a busy update on the UI thread (map control moving fast with updates) The UI Binding of this property is not updated, then when the busy update finish the property again updates the UI.

But if I put

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    RollDegrees = (OperationEntity as Level).RollDegrees;

                }));
```

Then the UI works perfect

Any hints of why this is happening?? Maybe something in the busy update?? Or this is a normal behaviour when the UI Dispatcher is full and busy??

Answer (score 0):

All UI elements should be updated only in UI thread. Each thread has it's own dispatcher. In case if you need update UI from non-UI thread, you should call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. Hence it is normal behavior.

In the first scenario, you're updating the property, but not from the UI thread. Hence the delay caused till the UI thread comes into action. When you're using the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, the UI is updated immediately.

So if you want to reflect some changes related to UI from a different thread, use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

Read more @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But I read that WPF marshalls property changes to UI Thread. But When the UI Thread is busy this does not work??

Comment: So.. WPF Automatic Marshalling puts low priority??